# Filter without relying to an html entity one line huge string based on a start end match and keep text in between the pattern no matter the length

Tags: sed, grep, freebsd

I have a one line file like this [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/xbti369J) but way longer.

My goal is to filter only parts of the string that
example1: start with `<a` end with `</a>`
example2: start with `PZ` end with `s16`
and so in every case keep text in between the match without relying to an html entity

I am on a `FreeBSD` and I already have a workaround that rely on html entities

1. Beautify to multiline `tidy -i -m -w 160 -ashtml -utf8 ~/file`
2. Delete lines if not contains string `sed -i '' '/\<\/a\>/!d' ~/file`

By the way I am trying to run a direct filter without relying to an html entity. For now I can get only the exact beginning of a match but I don’t know how much is long the string contents I am filtering, so I can’t be precise with the end of the match, see unexpected result steps to reproduce

#### Steps to reproduce unexpected result

```bsh
wget -O ~/file https://pastebin.com/raw/xbti369J
```

```bsh
grep -E -o ".{0,0}PZ.{0,46}" ~/file
```

[Result](https://pastebin.com/UNAczqm6)

###### We get wrong lines since we asked fixed lengths

```
PZ</td><td class="s15">€ 1.20</td><td class="s16
PZ</td><td class="s15"></td><td class="s16">A</t
```

###### Goal is to get lines result pattern no matter the length like this below

```
PZ</td><td class="s15">€ 1.20</td><td class="s16
PZ</td><td class="s15"></td><td class="s16
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a non-greedy match, anchored with lookarounds - something like perl's `m/(?<=PZ)(.*?)(?=s16)/g`

Comment: Please give imput examples that are long enough to cover several edge cases, but not filled with useless junk, and give the expected output.

Comment: Hi @Philippos I added some steps to reproduce unexpected result, if you need more floor to answer I will be here

Comment: You seem to be writing a web scraper.  Trying to do that using regular expressions alone is pretty much doomed to failure, you need an actual HTML parser.  So, use a language with good web scraping libraries.  Perl or Python, for example - the "best" choice is probably whichever language you are most familiar with that isn't shell.  I mostly use the [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/release/Web-Scraper) perl module these days, it works well and it's fairly easy to knock up a custom scraper.  The hardest/most time-consuming part is analysing the HTML structure to figure out what to extract.

Comment: @cas Which HTML parser would be able to match `PZ…s16` without caring for any HTML tags?

Comment: @Philippos any of them.  look for a td element's contents ending in PZ, then extract it and the next two td elements. Munge as required.   More importantly, this question is probably at least partially an XY problem, and the extraction the OP is asking for is due to their mistaken belief that regexps are a good way to extract data from structured text like html, coupled with either lack of knowledge that html parsers exist and/or an unwillingness to use them.   Most attempts to use regexps on html are due to a preference for quick and dirty hacks over doing it correctly and accurately.

Comment: @cas I wrote »without caring for any HTML tags«, but you answered with »td elements«, which is obviously caring for HTML tags. In the examples, the `PZ` is inside a td element, but the question doesn't say so, so it could also appear in a different tag, an attribute or a comment. While I agree that there is a chance of an XY problem, I learned to mistrust examples, because they can be midleading.

Comment: "PZ" is obviously inside a `<td>` element because it is immediately followed by `</td>`.   As for "without caring for any HTML tags", I deliberately ignored that because it's nonsense meant solely to exclude the only proper way of extracting data from HTML - i.e. with a parser.  Regexps alone won't work, the best you'll achieve that way will be fragile and unreliable.  See [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/), and [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML...](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/137158),

Comment: and also [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/137158)

Comment: @cas, I suggest to read my posts before you answer. Again, you refer to the example, but I told you I learned to mistrust examples. Too often they handle just a special case. The title clearly requests to filter *without relying to an html entity*. You made your point you think the OP is thinking the wrong direction. Maybe, but please respect my remark to take the request seriously and ignore that it's markup language at all. Thank you.

Comment: No, I don't think I will.   The OP is wrong in asking for that, and you are wrong in pandering to it.

Comment: Hi @cas first of all thanks for the Web::Scraper perl module suggestion, but I would keep that for another topic. Your observations are smart because you understood that my log example was an ethical scrape. Again that was just a public shared raw to explain the goal direction. I kindly ask you to see this topic as for dealing with text files, if lucky with a tab delimiter. So I asked to do not relying on any specific html entity, but plain text patterns. Again, that’s why I accepted Philippos answer. I hope you will accept too, and we will join a separated web scrapers topic soon together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select each sniplet from a `PZ` to the nearest `s16`, you need a non-greedy match, which is not supported by `grep` (extended) regular expressions, but GNU `grep` has the `-P`erl option for Perl-style expressions:

```
grep -P -o "PZ.*?s16" ~/file
```

The Perl expression `.*?' stands for the shortest match of any characters that will make the whole expression match.

This is probably still not what you are looking for, because there are further `PZ` inside the matches, but as I understand your example, you only want those `PZ` that are followed by `s16` without another `PZ`in between. So let's get rid of unwanted stuff in a second step:

```
grep -P -o "PZ.*?s16" ~/file | sed 's/.*PZ/PZ/'
```

Comment: `grep -E -o "PZ.*?s16" ~/file | sed 's/.*PZ/PZ/'` your -P is my -E

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an XML parser like `xmllint`.

Use the XPath expression below to filter out text in between `a` elements:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//a/text()' <file>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this.

**1** GNU grep with PCRE enabled.
Here we utilize non greedy regex *? in tandem with negative look ahead to discard any PZ occurring between PZ & s16.

```bsh
grep -Po 'PZ(?:(?!PZ).)*?s16' file
```

---

**2**
In case you don't have access to such a version of grep, you can use the original, viz., Perl , which will have the regex support.

```bsh
perl -lne 'print for /PZ(?:(?!PZ).)*?s16/g' file
```

---

**3**
We can use sed to do this. In the first pass, we mark the PZ & s16 as BOL & EOL. Then pass on this modified input to a second sed which shall select lines that begin with PZ, end with s16, and mustn't comprise PZ in the interior.

```bsh
< file \
sed 's/PZ/\n&/g;s/s16/&\n/g' |
sed '/^PZ.*s16$/!d;/..*PZ/d' |
cat
```

---

**4**
We. will use just one invocation of sed in this. It requires GNU sed.

```bsh
sed '/\n/{
  /^PZ[^\n]*s16/!D
  s//&\n/;P;D;}
  s/PZ/\n&/g;D
' file
```

---